# preventdefault not preventing when its inside button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I could not make preventdefault to prevent action. I apologize if the answer is too easy but I simply cant find the error. why is it not preventing from entering the link? jsfiddle given below.

http://jsfiddle.net/zwY5p/34/

```
$('#theForm').click(function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('FORM!');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e != event`

```
$('#theForm').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('FORM!');
});
```

The parameter passed to the handler function is what you need to execute `preventDefault` on. In your code, you are passing `e` but calling `preventDefault` on `event`.

---

`preventDefault` prevents the default browser action. **It does *not* cancel the inline JavaScript**, since that runs first. If you have to override that, just remove it (no event listener necessary):

```
$('#theForm').removeAttr('onclick').
```

Comment: @DannyPelletier - `preventDefault` prevents the *default browser action*. It does not cancel the inline JavaScript, since that runs first. If you have to override that, just remove it (no event listener necessary): `$('#theForm').removeAttr('onclick')`.

Answer (score 2):

your event parameter name `e` and the variable you are using `event` are different,

```
$('#theForm').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('FORM!');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Other than the errors pointed out on other answers there's another small issue, specifically in your markup declaration:

```
<!-- Use either the closing tag or the slash (/) in the opening tag -->      
<button id="theForm" onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com'" /> 
go to google
</button>
```

On the topic, you have two **different** handlers attached to the `button` element, they are both handling the `click` event but they are still different and separate things. jQuery won't know about the handler defined in the markup:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('theForm');
jQuery._data( btn, "events" );
```

will return an array with a single element which is the handler added via jQuery.
Now you have to re-evaluate the need of two different handlers for the same element and event and apply conditions. Do you really need to do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

You're using 2 'click' events.
You end up using preventDefault once, and it's used after the 1st click event has ran.

If you make your button an href, then your preventDefault will be working.
It will also make more sense, as the JS will be separated from the HTML markup.

Also, of course you must use the same parameter name. (function(event), with event.preventDefault for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing "e" as an event to the function then you should prevent the default action only for that "e" that you have passed and not for "event".

```
$('#theForm').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('FORM!');
});
```

jQuery preventDefault() method: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/